# Pine script erase old line from inside if statement?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I'm trying to draw a horizontal line from a condition and then erase the line from when the previous condition was true, but I get an error if I put the code to delete in the if statement, and it won't draw any lines if I put the code to delete outside the if statement.

```
r = close > close[1] and close[1] > close[2]
selleverything = if r
l1 := line.new(bar_index[1], price1, bar_index, price1, color=color.red, style=line.style_solid, 
width=1, extend=dS1 ? extend.right : extend.both)
```

The above draws the lines ok, but if I add

```
line.delete(l1[1])
```

inside the if statement I get a "void expression cannot be assigned to a variable"

if I put the line.delete(l1[1]) outside the if statement no lines will be drawn.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The if statement in this example is under a variable declaration scope.

```
selleverything = if r
```

Move it to the global scope instead as in the example below:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
r = close > close[1] and close[1] > close[2]

var line l1 = na
price1 = close
dS1 = true

if r
    l1 := line.new(bar_index[1], price1, bar_index, price1, color=color.red, style=line.style_solid, width=1, extend=dS1 ? extend.right : extend.both)
    line.delete(l1[1])
```

1. Declared `price1` and `dS1` variables as they were missing (assign to your code accordingly)
2. Pre-declared line `l1` variable.
3. Moved the if statement to the global scope.